# PHP folder creation mkdir on macOS

Tags: php, macos, apache, vagrant, mkdir

Currently I'm developing a web application using a Linux box with vagrant. The Operating System that I am using to host the Linux box is macOS. When I use the function `mkdir()`, the permissions on the folder always seem to be read-only privileges. Because of this I cannot uploaded files from my application into this folder. I can however manually change the permissions on the folder, however I do not want this since the system has to dynamically create these folders.

Has anyone ever experienced this problem before and know of a way to resolve this?

Comment: Check the `umask` for the user php is creating the directory as.

Comment: I edited your post because MAC=Medium Access Control https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_access_control not a product from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an optional value at the end setting the permissions

```
mkdir("/path/to/your/directory/name", 0755);
```

You may want to check the ownership too. It maybe that your dir needs to be www-data in order that apache can write to it.

```
chown('path/to/file', 'www-data:www-data');
```

Comment: I've tried changing the permission but that doesn't appear to work. I haven't tried changing the owner of the file so I will check this out and let you know how this works.

Comment: function makeDir($dir){
  $bool = false;
  if(isset($dir)){   
   if(!file_exists($dir)){
    mkdir($dir, 0755);
    chown($dir, 'www-data');
    $bool = true;
   } 
  }
  return $bool;
 }